# Delphi / OracleDAC: creating wrapped function programmatically

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi, delphi-7

I'm having problems to create a wrapped function programmatically in Delphi 7 using OracleDAC.

I have a file with this script:

```
BEGIN
SYS.DBMS_DDL.CREATE_WRAPPED('CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ... ');
END;
```

If I try to run it with "TOraScript" (OracleDAC) I get an ORA-24230 error, telling me that PL/SQL is not valid.

**BUT, if I run the same script in SQLNavigator, everything goes OK, the function is created**.

Comment: You are using a fully qualified reference to DBMS_DDL. Not sure if that is the problem but, are you also doing it for the Function name? something like SCHEMA.MY_FUNCTION?

Comment: did u try just using execute instead of anon block?